# Gradient vs differences to remove non-stationarity in time series?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, derivative, differencing

When dealing with non-stationary time series (for instance, in auto-correlation analysis), differencing (computing absolute differences between consecutive samples/observations) is often regarded as the simplest method of de-trending the data.

In theory, the first derivative (similar to what is obtained when computing the [gradient using central differences](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)) should also remove any underlying trends in the time series. What would be the advantages/drawbacks of using one over the other?

Comment: Definitions can vary but time series are usually taken to be discretely sampled, so there is no derivative. Are you suggesting a continuous time series, or a continuous time approximating model? Or just a centered difference? The first obvious issue with the latter is that it then depends on future data. Another is that the random walk is a classic model for which the usual difference yields a nice IID sequence, but the centered difference would give an MA(1) process instead, so is less "natural" in that sense.

Comment: I was referring to the latter, I'm getting vastly different ACF/PACF plots in both case got curious since I was expecting very similar results. But judging by your comment I guess it's normal.